# algorithm optimization - smallest number having n divisiors

Tags: c++, algorithm

This problem is a programming version of [Problem 12](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12) from [projecteuler.net](http://projecteuler.net)..

The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural numbers. So the 7'th triangle number would be 1+2+3+4+5+6+7=28. The first ten terms would be:

```
1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45,55,...
```

triangle number 28 would be having following factors

```
28 = 1,2,4,7,28
```

We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five divisors.

What is the value of the first triangle number to have over N divisors?

(1 <= N <= 1000)

I have written code which is working for N=750.But it is taking long time for N=1000.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

#define LL long long

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int test;
    scanf("%d",&test);
    int v[10001]={0};
    int tnum=1,num=1;

    while(1)
    {
        int c=0;
        for(int i=1;i*i<=tnum;++i)
        {
            if(tnum%i==0)
            {
                ++c;
                if(i!=(tnum/i))
                {                       
                    ++c;
                }               
            }
        }
        if(v[c]==0)
            v[c]=tnum;

        //  cout << "c = "<<c<<" tnum = " << tnum << endl;
        if(c>1000)
        {
            break;
        }
        ++num;

        tnum += num; 
    }

    while(test--)
    {
        int n;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        ++n;
        while(v[n]==0)
        {
            ++n;
        }
        printf("%d\n",v[n]); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit 1 = Answer for this question - As we have to find the next triangle number having over n divisiors,we can brute force all triangle number and find their number of divisiors. Then we will see that a pattern for larger value of n(n>240)

Comment: Any reason for such non-formatted blobs?

Comment: @Deduplicator - formatting done

Comment: Isn't this the real fun of projecteuler? Trying to get to the best algorithm yourself? Write the formula down on a piece of paper and start expressing it in different forms. You may have a heureka moment that way.

Comment: @stefan I have been hitting my head so hard since last 5 hours , I couldn't come up with a formula..

Comment: @user3098272 well then you can solve another problem first and come back to this one once you either gained more knowledge or just cleared your mind. Trust me: project euler is great fun, but asking for help online will ruin it. Two small things: You really should improve the formatting, it's making your life as a developer unnecessarily hard. Second: don't use macros to define type names. write `typedef long long LL;`instead. It's much safer to use.

Comment: @stefan well thanks for the kind words. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 5):

If I told you how many divisors the number 938,839 has, and how many divisors the number 938,840 has, how would you find out the number of divisors of 938,839 * 938,840, using just the information that I gave you?

And how can you use that idea to make your algorithm run about 100 times faster?

Comment: This is not an answer.  Please comment after the question instead.

Comment: @wallyk: No, it's better than a direct answer.

Comment: (edited: I didn't feel like this was actually an answer. I didn't realize the comment that would be left would state that I thought it was specifically a critique or request for additional information, which it clearly isn't. It's clearly a pointer in the direction of an answer.)

Comment: @wallyk: I believe giving hints, rather than complete answers, is accepted on this site for things like Project Euler problems.

Comment: @neminem: You might note that he's neither critiquing nor requesting clarification from the author.  Read more than just the question mark.

Comment: While it is true that I just got access to that queue, I feel personally like a pointer in the general direction of an answer isn't an answer? (It is definitely true that that didn't leave quite the comment I expected it would. I feel like it isn't an answer, but I agree that it is not requesting clarification.)

Comment: @tmyklebu:  Point taken.

Comment: @JimLewis:  Indeed hints are allowed.  I didn't recognize them as hints though as they looked like clarification questions.

Comment: @gnasher729 yes I got that. If number m1 has n1 divisiors and m1+1 has n2 divisiors then m1(m1+1) has n1*n2 divisiors..Correct me If I am wrong..

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a hint. Since it's a projecteuler question, I'm not sure what the correct approach is. Should projecteuler questions even be asked here in the first place?

Comment: @neminem: It's not, strictly speaking, an answer.  You can probably find a rule saying that this should be migrated to a comment.  But that's dumb.  People don't solve Project Euler problems because it's their job, or because it's some technical challenge on the way to something they actually want to do; rather, they solve PE problems in order to learn something or to hone their problem solving skills.  A direct answer defeats that.

Comment: @tmyklebu I agree, that's reasonable, in this case. I hadn't run across projecteuler questions before. Now I know.

Comment: Answer for this question - As we have to find the next triangle number to have over n divisiors,we can brute force all triangle number and find their number of divisiors. Then we will see that a pattern for larger value of n(n>240)